# How to access custom fields in ASP.Net Identity User?

Tags: c#, asp.net, identity

I have added more custom fields to the ApplicationUser class from Asp.Net Identity. I've needed fields like user's full name, location and etc.

Now I need to access those parameters in some of the views. 
For example to get the UserName I can simply get it with `User.Identity.GetUserName()`.

How do I access the FullName, Location and other properties from the ApplicationUser class inside the views?

Comment: what have you tried do far?

Comment: I've tried adding this in my view, but i failed.

var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(User.Identity.Name);

Comment: Can you post your code please ?

Comment: var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(User.Identity.Name);

Shouldn't you put Email instead of Name ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you consider using [Claim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/claims?view=aspnetcore-2.2) ? Claim will automatically loaded to Context Identity when the user sign in.

Add claim when user is created

```
await userManager.AddClaimAsync(user.Id, new Claim("FullName", user.FullName));
```

Create extension to Identity

```
namespace MyApps.Extension
{
    public static class IdentityExtension
    {
        public static string GetFullName(this IIdentity identity)
        {
            if (identity == null)
                return null;

            var fullName = (identity as ClaimsIdentity).FirstOrNull("FullName");

            return fullName;
        }


        internal static string FirstOrNull(this ClaimsIdentity identity, string claimType)
        {
            var val = identity.FindFirst(claimType);

            return val == null ? null : val.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Later use

```
httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.GetFullName()
```