# How to view custom field added to Asp.Net Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-identity

I added a custom class that extends IdentityUser

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace RacePull.Models
{
    public class AppUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Everything is configured for the DbContext and users are able to set their display name on registration and I am seeing it populate in the Database.

My question is how can I display this information in my views?

Ex. _LoginPartial.cshtml

```
@inject SignInManager<AppUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<AppUser> UserManager

<ul class="navbar-nav">
@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
{
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a  class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Manage/Index" title="Manage">Hello @User.Identity?.name!</a>
            var user = context.UserProfiles.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserId == id);

    </li>
```

I want to replace @User.Identity?.name! with the users newly added 'DisplayName'

How can I use this new property in my views?

When trying User.Identity.DisplayName nothing works

Comment: use the generic `IdentityDbContext<TUser, TRole, TKey, TUserLogin, TUserRole, TUserClaim>` class to use the custom models.

Comment: How would I get my new column I added?

Answer (score 0):

Your question had been answered before Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57683589/how-to-access-custom-fields-in-asp-net-identity-user) to see your answer.